# Build trigger is not invoked on push for Azure Git repositories

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have my git repository hosted on Azure DevOps. I created a new yaml based build pipeline in the `master` branch and have set the trigger section to two existing branches. Other branches don't have a `azure-pipeline.yml` file nor any kind of branch policies are set for this DevOps project.

```
trigger:
  batch: 'true'
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - develop
```

The trigger gets invoked for every change in the `master` branch as expected. But is ignoring any pushes to the `develop` branch.

If I configure a build pipeline with the visual editor and define the exact two branches there, for every push a build will be triggered.

Any idea how Azure Pipeline respects the build definition also for other branches without copy and pasting the whole definition for every possible branch?

Comment: this looks like it should, so the only way this might not work - your branch is not called develop

Comment: There is definitelly a `develop` branch ;) I also created a brand new DevOps Project and experience the same. It's not only the `develop` branch. It's every other also.

Comment: no, it works perfectly fine, check your indentation or something

Comment: Have a look at the new project: https://dev.azure.com/tpcemedia/BuildTest pushing to `develop` triggers nothing.

Comment: A fix for this issue should have rolled out last week to all Azure Repo's accounts.

Answer (score 1):

> Build trigger is not invoked on push for Azure Git repositories

I have created a sample with the syntax:

```
trigger:
  batch: 'true'
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - Dev
```

And it works fine on my side. Then I check the new project you provided, but I found that the `.yml` file is incomplete and does not contain a `trigger:` node.

So, to resolve this issue, we need to double check the `.yml` file you modified in under the `master` branch, and you build `.yml` file is you modified.

Besides, when we edit the build pipeline, there is a extended button, we could select the option  `Triggers` to set the build trigger with visual editor:

[image]

If above not help you, you can try to create a new build pipeline, set the trigger only with Develop branch, check if it works fine, then return to the previous with `master` 
 and `develop` branch.

If all of the above methods are not worked, you may need share a detailed sample and some steps, the reason for this problem may be hidden in the corner we ignore.

Hope this helps.